# Divergence and Curl in Spherical Coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Using these definitions, how would you solve for div $\textbf{f}$ and and curl $\textbf{f}$?What are $f_p$, $f_\theta$, and $f_\phi$?

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Comment: Thank you. But I still don't really understand what it's saying. It just uses A instead of e... How do you calculate $A_p$/$e_p$, etc.?

Comment: If your book doesn't indicate what $e_\rho$, for example, signifies, then you're sunk.  That could mean a lot of things--a unit vector along the $\rho$ direction, a potentially non-unit vector, and so on.  $f_\rho, f_\theta, f_\phi$ are almost certainly partial derivatives.

Comment: It actually does give definitions for $e_p$, $e_\theta$, and $e_\phi$, but not $f_p$, etc. If it is a partial derivative, why do they also use $\frac{d}{d\theta}$? To indicate second order partial derivatives? Thanks.

Comment: They use those to indicate partial derivatives of more complicated expressions and second derivatives, yes.

Comment: Thanks. So it's just another way of writing $\frac{d^2F}{d\theta^2}$, etc?